# Running SSIS Package from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, permissions

I am trying to run an SSIS package from SQL Server.  I was able to successfully import the package and run it manually. I was also able to run it manually from the SSIS Catalog. Neither work from the agent job.  Oddly enough, when I set package source to sql server, the package does not show even though it is listed in the MSDB folder.

Account I am running the job from seems to have permission and I am running SSMS as admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste code and screen shots?

Comment: Is the job schedule executing and erroring, or not executing?

Comment: Do you have environment variables defined?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Run `SELECT 'Found in SSISDB', * FROM SSISDB.catalog.folders AS F INNER JOIN SSISDB.catalog.projects AS P ON P.folder_id = F.folder_id INNER JOIN SSISDB.catalog.packages AS PKG ON PKG.project_id = P.project_id WHERE PKG.name LIKE '%MYPackageName%'` or this [query](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html) and let us know which one listed the package you are trying to run

Comment: The job is not executing.  When I try to run the job manually it errors out and tells me to view history. view history says to check execution report. when I execute straight from the catalog it runs the package just fine.

Comment: billinkc; the first query returns the package I am trying to run

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQL Server 2012+ version, which supports package deployment model. Packages get stored in Integration service catalog. So, while creating job select package source as **SSIS catalog** (see screenshot below)

[image]